# How to create a static front page with blog posts in Sage?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, roots-sage

I am trying to create a static homepage custom template, 
with a structure like this:

1. Hero
2. Some images and texts
3. **[Blog Posts]**
4. Footer

The problem is my code showing posts with post type: page, instead of post type: post.

I use Sage (Roots.io)(Blade template engine), creating a template called *template-home.blade.php*.
I've already tried to copy code from *content.blade.php*, and use it on my *template-home.blade.php*.

This is the code from *content.blade.php* that I use to get blog posts:

```php
        <article @php post_class() @endphp>
            <header>
              <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ get_permalink() }}">{!! get_the_title() !!}</a></h2>
              @include('partials/entry-meta')
            </header>
            <div class="entry-summary">
              @php the_excerpt() @endphp
            </div>
          </article>
```

---

Expected results: 
It should show all posts with post type: **post**. 
Like "Blog Post Title 1", "Blog Post Title 2", etc.

Current results:
Copied code show posts with post type: **page**. 
Like "Home", "About", etc.

---

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this following solution:

1. Get the posts with Home Controller:

   ```php
   public function blog_posts(){
       $posts_per_page = 4;
       $query_args = [
           'post_type'           => 'post',
           'post_status'         => 'publish',
       ];

       $blog = get_posts($query_args);

       return $blog;
   }
   ```

1.1. Or get the posts with this code:

```
$blog_posts = collect(get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
]))->map(function ($post) {
    return (object) [
        'categories' => get_the_category($post),
        'title'      => get_the_title($post),
        'url'        => get_permalink($post),
        'date'       => get_the_date('M d, Y', $post),
        'excerpt'    => substr_replace(get_the_excerpt($post), "", -16),
        'image'      => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post)
    ];
});
```

2. Call it from Home Template:

   ```php
   {{ print_r($blog_posts) }}
   ```

---

Example (rendering 4 columns of blog posts):

```
    {{-- Blogposts Loop --}}
    @foreach ($blog_posts as $key=>$post)
      @if ($key < 4)
        <div class="grid__item medium--one-half large--three-twelfths">
          <div class="blog-item">
            @if($post->image)
              <a href="{{ $post->url }}">
                <div class="blog-item__image" style="background-image: url({{ $post->image }})" title="{{ $post->title }}"></div>
              </a>
            @else
              <a href="{{ $post->url }}">
                <div class="blog-item__image" style="background-color: #eee" title="{{ $post->title }}"></div>
              </a>
            @endif
            <p class="blog-item__meta">
              {{ $post->date }} /
              @foreach ($post->categories as $category)
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>">
                  {{ $category->name.' ' }}
                </a>
              @endforeach
            </p>
            <h4 class="blog-item__title"><a href="{{ $post->url }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h4>
            <div class="blog-item__excerpt">
              @php echo $post->excerpt @endphp <a class="blog-item__excerpt-link" href="{{ $post->url }}">Read More...</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      @endif
    @endforeach
```